# Combine scoped fields_for and one additional form rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say i'm writing a simple TODO application. There are three hardcoded projects to which user is able to add a tasks (using `fields_for` method) so basically, my form looks like that:

```
# task.first_project, task.second_project and task.third_project are a scopes for
# retrieving tasks, which belongs to chosen project.

= form_for setup_project(@project) do |f|
  h3 First project's tasks:
  = f.fields_for :tasks, f.object.tasks.first_project do |ff|
    = ff.text_field :title
    = ff.hidden_field :project_id, value: 1

  h3 Second project's tasks:
  = f.fields_for :tasks, f.object.tasks.second_project do |ff|
    = ff.text_field :title
    = ff.hidden_field :project_id, value: 2

  h3 Third project's tasks:
  = f.fields_for :tasks, f.object.tasks.third_project do |ff|
    = ff.text_field :title
    = ff.hidden_field :project_id, value: 3
```

I have also a form helper for adding one empty task form at the end of task forms list:

```
  def setup_project(project)
    1.times { project.tasks.build }
    project
  end
```

And that's what is my main problem. This code from form helper works perfect only when i'm using `fields_for` without any scopes. When i'm adding them, the additional form build is not shown.

**Please note: Above example is just a very simplified version of what i'm actually programming. Please do not advice me to rewrite my app to have more dynamical projects adding functionality or something like that. Trust me, it really needs to work in such a *strange* way :)**

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it working by using the following code:

```
# task.first_project, task.second_project and task.third_project are a scopes for
# retrieving tasks, which belongs to chosen project.

= form_for @project do |f|
  h3 First project's tasks:
  = f.fields_for :tasks, setup_tasks(f.object.tasks.first_project) do |ff|
    = ff.text_field :title
    = ff.hidden_field :project_id, value: 1

  h3 Second project's tasks:
  = f.fields_for :tasks, setup_tasks(f.object.tasks.second_project) do |ff|
    = ff.text_field :title
    = ff.hidden_field :project_id, value: 2

  h3 Third project's tasks:
  = f.fields_for :tasks, setup_tasks(f.object.tasks.third_project) do |ff|
    = ff.text_field :title
    = ff.hidden_field :project_id, value: 3
```

form_helper:

```
def steup_tasks(tasks)
  tasks << tasks.build
end
```

But i have no idea if that's the proper solution. If you know any better, please share it :)